# Guice CreationException - No implementation for type Foo was bound

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Need some help to understand this error and possible way to solve it.

So I have a Type like this:

```
class Foo {
   static final class Bar {}

   @Inject
   Foo(TypeA a, @Nullable Set<Bar> b) {}
}
```

In order to make Foo injectable, I need to fulfill dependency for
params a and b, now I have no problem to provide Type a
implementation, its not null, so I have a @Provides method in the
packages Module class. But what about b? Its a nullable, how to write
@Provides with a parameter that can be nullable? My guess is it
shouldn't be required and Guice should understand the annotation...
But something isn't working right, I got this error:

1) No implementation for `java.util.Set<Foo$Bar>` was bound.

And here is the @Provides method (which didn't work atm)

```
@Provides @Nullable
public Foo provideFoo(TypeA a, @Nullable Set<Foo.Bar> b) {
    return new Foo(a, b);
}
```

I know the nested class is not public nor the constructor, so maybe
guice can't access it but even if I make them all public (which I
don't really want) the error still remains... Is there something I am
missing?

Comment: Do you really need null-collection? Could you use empty set?

Comment: Not really, but the original thought is also not to require client to provide a Set object (construct an empty Set even if the client doesn't really care), the Foo constructor checks null and will creates an empty Set if needed. I know that I could overload the constructor by just adding Foo(TypeA a) and remove the @Nullable. Maybe I should think about that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between not having any binding for `Set<Bar>` and having a binding for `Set<Bar>` that is `null`.

You'd need an `@Provides` method that returns a `Set<Bar>` (that may be `null`) or something like `bind(Bar.class).toProvider(Providers.ofInstance(null))` in order to be able to provide the second parameter to `Foo`'s constructor.

Also note that your `@Provides` method for `Foo` is just calling the `@Inject` annotated constructor directly, so it's not necessary at all. I'd also say it'd be preferable to bind to an empty `Set<Bar>` rather than to `null`.

Comment: so as your suggestion, should I refactor this piece of code to something like this (as seems to be implied by an earily reply from Stas Kurilin).  Two constructors, Foo(TypeA a), and Foo(TypeA a, Set<Foo.Bar> b), and then @Inject the first?